# How do you obtain the final item in Carrot ASI?

Tags: artificial-superintelligence

I have 14/15 items in Carrot ASI.  The developer told me that the 15th is obtained from somewhere in the initial loading screen and that it's very rare.

I've been watching the chess game that plays out on that screen.  And, each time it's the same game -- leading to the Human Resigns.

Is there a change in that Chess outcome that leads to obtaining the final item? If so, what is the pattern to look for?

Comment: do you have the item Kasaparov's king? I have that item and it features the king chess piece but I'm not sure how I got it

Comment: Just searched up Kasparov’s king and from what I’m seeing you probably want the initial game to end in “Computer Wins” because that would explain how to get it (Your AI checkmates / takes the king before the “human” can resign)

Comment: @Yout Ried yeah. I figured that. Do you know if there's a pattern that can be spotted without waiting for it to complete the entire game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it's a passive achievement that doesn't notify you when you've accomplished it. Let the game on screen play out until the human resigns. Then the item will quietly appear in your items list.

Answer (score -2):

It seems that it won't notify you when you've accomplished it. You have to wait and let the game on screen play out until the human resigns. Then the item will appear in your items list.

Comment: You seem to have copied this almost directly from David M's answer, without adding any other helpful information.